# Alternative to class() that does not distinguish between "numeric" and "integer"

Tags: r

Given a data.frame, I would like to test if all the columns are of the same "class". if they are I'd like to leave the data.frame as is. If they aren't I'd like to keep all columns that match the first variables class and drop any that are not of that class. The exception being that, for my purposes, integer and numeric are equal.

For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(numeric,numeric,integer,factor)
```

Would be:

```
data.frame(numeric,numeric,integer)
```

Additionally

```
dat <- data.frame(character,character,integer)
```

Would be:

```
data.frame(character,character)
```

And finally:

```
dat <- data.frame(numeric,numeric,numeric,factor)
```

Would be:

```
data.frame(numeric,numeric,numeric)
```

Comment: I also wish I had better tools for not distinguishing between integer and numeric. For a while I thought `mode` would help, but I don't think that's reliable.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but why not simply use `dat[,sapply(dat, is.numeric)]`?  Because `is.numeric(1L)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: I'll update my question with some more of my edge case scenarios so you can see why not.

Comment: I'm trying to capture two situations different situations. Not distinguising between two different types of numeric columns would be useful.

Comment: To get your code to run, you need to change `tmp` to `dat`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien apparently not what I thought it meant.

Comment: I still don't see what's wrong with `dat[,sapply(dat, is.numeric)]`.  If the first column is character/factor, then just negate it: `dat[,!sapply(dat, is.numeric)]`.

Comment: I'd like to know what you want to do in the case of a factor first column. It looks like you want to keep anything with that class then, but do you ignore the numerics in that case, I don't keep them or keep them *and* any columns that are factors?

Comment: Also you seem to be confusing rows and columns in your text. I presume we are only considering variables in the data frame?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen -1 this is a very confusing question. Instead of pseudo examples and a simple real-case example, it would be better to give us an actual reproducible for both cases your show in the first code block. I'll happily remove the -1 if you can edit and provide more examples and output. See the Answers from Andrie and I for one ambiguity that would not be there if you'd shown real examples and real expected output.

Comment: I agree, even trying to explain it I'm having a bit of difficulty. I'll rethink how I'm asking the question. Perhaps providing some background would be helpful as well.

Comment: Does either of @Andrie's or my answers do what you want? If so, take the example `dat2` from my Answer as an example if appropriate and if Andrie's answer does what you want I can delete mine. Then we're done?

Comment: Thoughts? My `surveydata` package on github has tools to do this type of extraction: https://github.com/andrie/surveydata. The vignette is a good starting point.

Comment: I have to noodle on this a bit. I recommend against answering until I can sort out how best to present my problem.

Comment: I think I've made this more complicated than it needs to be. Joran's initial comment was exactly in line with my thinking. Basically, the problem wouldn't exist if class() did not distinguish between numeric and integer. Which, thinking about it more directly can probably just be done by wrapping that function.

Comment: Allright, I think this update makes it as clear as it's going to get.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback - I needed to talk this one out!

Comment: In that case (and it is a helpful edit +1) I think my slight modification of your `if()` does what you want.

Comment: @Andrie We've discussed `surveydata` and while I think you did a great job with it, most of my work starts and ends with CSV files and plain text questionnaires so my process is a bit different. Actually we should have an offline discussion soon. I've been working on automated summarization directly from a questionnaire that's kind of like "one click" survey analysis. The "last" thing I'm having trouble with is identifying multipunch questions programmatically in the presence of partial data. Tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate the commentary and your answers, in the end all I needed was a class() function  that does not distinguish between integer and numeric. Which can be accomplished with a simple wrapper.

```
class.wrap <- function(x) {
test <- class(x) 
if(test == "integer") test <- "numeric"
return(test)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  a=as.integer(1:26), b=as.integer(26:1), c=as.numeric(1:26), d=as.factor(1:26)
)
```

Create two helper functions:

```
is.numint <- function(x)is.numeric(x) || is.integer(x)
is.charfact <- function(x)is.character(x) || is.factor(x)
```

Return only numeric columns:

```
head(dat[, sapply(dat, is.numint)])
    a  b  c
1   1 26  1
2   2 25  2
3   3 24  3
4   4 23  4
5   5 22  5
```

Return only factor columns:

```
head(dat[, sapply(dat, is.charfact), drop=FALSE])
  d
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
```

---

Combining this approach, and rewriting your function:

```
dropext <- function(x){
  is.numint <- function(x)is.numeric(x) || is.integer(x)
  is.charfact <- function(x)is.character(x) || is.factor(x)
  cl <- rep(NA, length(x))
  cl[sapply(x, is.numint)] <- "num"
  cl[sapply(x, is.charfact)] <- "char"
  x[, cl == unique(cl)[1], drop=FALSE]
}

dropext(dat)
    a  b  c
1   1 26  1
2   2 25  2
3   3 24  3
4   4 23  4
5   5 22  5
```

Comment: That's basically what I said in my comment... `is.numeric(1L)` is `TRUE` so you don't need to test `is.integer` too.

Comment: The issue is more complex than this though. The second example has a factor in the first column so he wants, if I understand correctly, to maintain the char/factor variables, but ignore numerics for the purposes of the entire if etc.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Answer edited. I think this does what the OP described.

Comment: @Andrie This gives a different result on `dat2` from my Answer; it keeps both factors and characters. It isn't clear if the OP wants to keep both or just one. The code in the `if()` suggests he wants only one (he keeps the variables with class of the first component), but it is ambiguous what is wanted.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I agree that the question is somewhat ambiguous. I am basing my answer on a hunch / guess that the OP is describing survey data, and I respond based on my typical workflow when working with survey data. Either way, my approach can easily be modified, as you pointed out in your answer.

Comment: +1 by the way - the comments weren't aimed at your Answer just so the OP would see what the issues/ambiguities were.

Comment: @Andrie It is indeed survey data. And this answer is helpful but Gavin is correct in identifying that I'd like it to also work in the reverse. I've tried to add a bit of background to the question as well.

Comment: I feel strange being called OP by someone I've had telephone conversations with! :P

Comment: Yes, it is a bit weird, isn't it, Brandon?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
if(length(unique(cl <- sapply(dat, class))) > 1 && 
   any(!sapply(dat, is.numeric))) {
    dat <- dat[ , which(cl == cl[1]), drop = FALSE]
}
```

This assumes that in the following example:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(A = factor(sample(LETTERS, 26, replace = TRUE)),
                   B = factor(sample(LETTERS, 26, replace = TRUE)),
                   C = sample(LETTERS, 26, replace = TRUE),
                   dat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


> sapply(dat2, class)
               A                B                C 
        "factor"         "factor"      "character" 
as.integer.1.26. as.integer.26.1. as.numeric.1.26. 
       "integer"        "integer"        "numeric"
```

you want **only** the factor variables, i.e. you want to distinguish between character and factor variables - which is what your code appears to do.

For this example I used

```
if(length(unique(cl <- sapply(dat2, class))) > 1 &&
   any(!sapply(dat2, is.numeric))) {
    dat2 <- dat2[ ,which(cl == cl[1]), drop = FALSE]
}
```

which results in

```
> head(dat2)
  A B
1 D G
2 P D
3 C T
4 X F
5 N R
6 A E
> sapply(dat2, class)
       A        B 
"factor" "factor"
```

On `dat`, the above `if()` statement would not change `dat`:

```
>     if(length(unique(cl <- sapply(dat, class))) > 1 && 
+         any(!sapply(dat, is.numeric))) {
+         dat <- dat[ , which(cl == cl[1]), drop = FALSE]
+     }
> head(dat)
  as.integer.1.26. as.integer.26.1. as.numeric.1.26.
1                1               26                1
2                2               25                2
3                3               24                3
4                4               23                4
5                5               22                5
6                6               21                6
```